# How to use align gather in itemize or list environment?

Tags: align, itemize, gather

I would like to number each equations under the itemize environment by using align or  command.However it doesn't work well.Thank you for your patience in advance.
The errors:
Runaway argument?
 with\quad U(c_t,l_t)&=\theta \ln c_t+(1-\theta )\ln (1-l_t), 0<\theta \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \align was complete.
 
                   \par 
But I don't know how to correct it.
My codes are following:

```
\section{Economic Environment}
\begin{itemize}
\item{Consumption of a representative agent at period-t:}$c_t$.
\item{Labor of a representative agent at period-t:}$l_t$.

\item{The expected value of lifetime utility:}

\qquad$\biggl[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\beta^t U(c_t,l_t)\biggr]$
\begin{align}
with\quad U(c_t,l_t)&=\theta\ln c_t+(1-\theta)\ln (1-l_t), 0<\theta<1.\\
\item {Final output:}y
\item {Capital of equipment and Structure:}k&=k_e+k_s.\\
\item {Utilization rate of equipment:}h.
\item {Total factor productivity(TFP):}z.
\item{Production technology:}
\qquad y&=F(h k_e,k_s,l,z)\\
    &=z(h k_e)^{\alpha_e} k_s^{\alpha_s} l^{(1-\alpha_e-\alpha_s)}, \quad 
 0<\alpha_e,\alpha_s,\alpha_e+\alpha_s<1 \\
\item{Investment in equipment and structures:}

\qquad i&=i_e+i_s \\
\item{Adjustment costs that can be used for consumption, c,investment in 
 structures and equipment:}

\qquad a&=a_e+a_s\\
\qquad a_e&=A_e(k_e'/q,k_e/q;\eta)\\
      &=e^{\eta}\phi_e{(k_e'/q-\kappa_e k_e/q)}^2/(k_e/q) \quad with 
\phi_e,\kappa_e>0,\\
\intertext{and}a_s&=A_s(k_s',k_s)\\
              &=\phi_s{(k_s'-\kappa_s k_s)}^2/k_s.
\item{Resource constraints:}

\qquad y&=a+c+i_e+i_s
\item{The stock of structures accumulation equation:}

\qquad k_s'&=(1-\delta_s)k_s+i_s, where  0<\delta<1.\\
\item $q$: The current state of the technology for producing equipment.
\item{The equipment accumulation equation:}

\qquad k_e'&=(1-\delta_e(h))k_e+i_eq\\
\item{Equipment depreciation function:}

\qquad \delta_e(h)&=\frac{b}{\omega}h^\omega, \omega>1.\\
\item{Process of TFP:}

\qquad z_{t+1}&=\gamma_z^{t+1}e^{\zeta_{t+1}},\\

\qquad where $\zeta_{t+1}$ follows the distribution 
function Z(\zeta'|\zeta)&=Pr\{\zeta_{t+1}=\zeta'|\zeta_t=\zeta\}.\\
\item{Process of investment specific technology:}

\qquad q_{t+1}&=\gamma_q^{t+1}e^\eta_{t+1},\\

\qquad where $\eta_{t+1}$ follows the distribution 
function $H(\eta'|\eta)=Pr\{\eta_{t+1}=\eta'|\eta_t=\eta\}.$
\end{align}
\end{itemize}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Full minimal example please. Remember gather require the amsmath package, but since you did not post a full minimal example we do not know if you loaded it

Comment: I used amsmath package. https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zEGz.png is what I want to get but with the numbers of each equations.

Comment: As I said update your question with a full example. When people have to guess half your example they are much less inclined to help.

Comment: your example should be a document that people can run to see the error, but `gather` can not possibly work interleaved with `\item` in that way, it is very hard to guess what you intend it to do???

Comment: in gather environment had not to be `item`s...

Comment: This is still not a minimal example, we need something we can copy and run as is, we don't know the class you're using or the preamble

Comment: I thought I could use gather interleaved with \item, now I use \equation and figure out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really understandable, the code fragment is not complete and the posted image appears to be showing unrelated text.

However this runs without error, the result is not really understandable though: it forms  a strange mixture of bullet points and numbered equations, but hopefully you can edit it to make something usable.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

 \begin{itemize}
    \item $c_t$: Consumption of a representative agent at period-$t$.
    \item $l_t$: Labor of a representative agent at period-$t$.
\begin{equation}
    E\biggl[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\beta^t U(c_t,l_t)\biggr]
\end{equation}
    with
\begin{equation}
U(c_t,l_t)=\theta\ln c_t+(1-\theta)\ln (1-l_t), 0<\theta<1.
\end{equation}
    \item $y$: Final Output.
    \item $k=k_e+k_s$: Capital equipment and Structure.
    \item $h$: Utilization rate of equipment.
    \item $z$: Total Factor Productivity.
\begin{equation}
    y=F(h k_e,k_s,l,z)=z(h k_e)^{\alpha_e} k_s^{\alpha_s} l^{(1-\alpha_e-
    \alpha_s)}, \quad 0<\alpha_e,\alpha_s,\alpha_e+\alpha_s<1
\end{equation}
Production Technology.
   \item $i=i_e+i_s$: Investment in equipment and structures.
   \item $a=a_e+a_s$: Adjustment costs that can be used for 
    consumption,c,investment in structures and equipment.
    $y=a+c+i_e+i_s$: Resource Constraints.\\
    $k_s'=(1-\delta_s)k_s+i_s$, where $0<\delta<1$: The stock of structures 
    accumulation equation.
    \item $q$: The current state of the technology for producing equipment.
    $k_e'=(1-\delta_e(h))k_e+i_eq$:The equipment accumulation equation.
\begin{equation}
    \delta_e(h)=\frac{b}{\omega}h^\omega, \omega>1
\end{equation}
Equipment depreciation 
    function.
\begin{equation}
    z_{t+1}=\gamma_z^{t+1}e^{\zeta_{t+1}}.
\end{equation}
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```